# How to rewrite URL with `.htaccess`, which disallows direct links?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I created my website with some files in `htdocs` folder, such as: `.htaccess`, `detail.php` ... In past, I used an old URL structure for my website: `detail.php?id=12`. Then, I have used a new one: `product/12`, by using this simple `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^product/([0-9]+)/?$" "/detail.php?$1"
```

And now, I do not want any user can access my website with old URL structure. If you do not mind, could you show me: how to rewrite URL with `.htaccess`, which disallows direct links?

> In my speech, `disallows direct links` means `404` for direct links.

Comment: By "disallow old links" you mean, make them return 404?

Comment: I think that it is never very clever to refuse a part, sometimes important, of the visitors, for technical reasons. You should find a method to redirect these pages to the new url. (Make a product2 page, for new rewrites, and redirect from the old product page all access to the new url)

Comment: I understood that. However, a 301 redirect could update all links for search engines. While with 404 you lose the SEO...

Answer (score 1):

To disallow your old links , you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?id=.*$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

This will redirect your old links to  **404** error page of your site.